What is the definition of Force?
I've come across so many abstract definitions of force—like "an interaction between two bodies" or "something that changes the state of motion or shape of a body." But what exactly is a force?
One issue I see with the "change of state of motion" definition is that it assumes we're observing motion relative to an inertial frame. But then, how do we define an inertial frame? I've seen it described (using a modern take on Newton's first law) as "a frame in which a body with no net force acting on it moves in a straight line at constant velocity." But here’s where the problem arises: if we use the concept of "force" to define what an inertial frame is, aren’t we just going in circles?

Force is the rate at which momentum is changed. But was is momentum, physically?

@JAlex You are using Newton's second law as the definition of Force, but then  how is it a law? It will have no content but just merely be a definition.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/827818/is-the-definition-of-inertial-reference-frame-circular

Exactly. Newton’s 2nd is just that - a definition. It always holds true.

@controlgroup that is not true, 2nd law is not a definition of force. 2nd law states that acceleration of a body is proportional to net force, which is vector sum of all forces acting on the body. It does not say anything about magnitude and direction of any individual force; those we must infer from experience or other laws (e.g. gravity force, electric force, and so on).

I can't tell the difference between two newtons up and one newton down and just one newton up. Net force is interesting that way: $F=ma$ for any combination $F=F_1+F_2+...$ of forces. It's a linear equation in that way.

My shelf can tell the difference.

@controlgroup You can't if you base your idea of force solely on the 2nd law. The 2nd law equation $\sum_{n\in \text{forces acting on the body}} \mathbf F_n = m\mathbf a$ does not define the component forces, only gives us a way to measure the net force, which is defined as their vector sum. Individual forces have effects other than acceleration, e.g. deformation of the body. If forces are concentrated to small areas, you will see effects of deformation in places where the forces act.

One thing I don't understand about your question, is the connection you seem to be suggesting between the definition of an inertial frame, and the definition of a force. Evidently, we apply the concept of forces in non-inertial frames all the time, right? It's just that to use this concept in non-inertial frames requires accounting for "fictitious" or "pseudo" forces. The surface of the earth is not inertial for various reasons, for example the Coriolis force. So we account for that in our equations when it becomes important. These equations are still force equations, so what is the issue?


But what is momentum, physically? === Eiher: 1) A compressive distortion in  the spacetime metric that persists in time (mass), or 4D rotation that does not propagate in time (photons). The energy in one photon rotation is the planck energy. The nuclear forces are more interesting.


@Dale Any reason why my edit was reversed? Like is it not allowed or something?

@ojasdessai yes, it is against the site policy to modify a question in such a way as to invalidate answers you have already received. Those answers did answer the question as it was written at the time they answered it. False, misguided, or wrong answers should be downvoted (with or without comment), rather than modifying the question.

This is a good and fundamental question and such an important topic in teaching mechanics, but it is widely misunderstood.
A lot of people believe, incorrectly, that force is defined by the formula
$$
\mathbf F = m\mathbf a,
$$
or by the formula
$$
\mathbf F = \frac{d\mathbf p}{dt}.
$$
This view suggests that to determine the force acting on some body (its magnitude and direction), we can measure acceleration of this body, or rate of change of its momentum, and then use the above formulae to find the force the body experiences.
That works, but in fact, this is a way to determine only net force (sum of all forces) acting on the body. Also, it is a definition that is based on belief in validity of the 2nd law equation; it does not allow for the force to not obey it, so this equation becomes a definition, and Newton's 2nd law ceases to be an empirically based law. And we can determine the particular force of interest (e.g. gravity force, or friction force, or thrust force of a jet engine) this way only if we can get the body to experience only this one force, so it is the net force. But such situations are rare; and when they do effectively happen (e.g. electron in electric field or planet moving in empty space around the Sun), the concept of force in that situation isn't very useful and important. Usually on Earth, when body is in motion, there are several forces at play (e.g. gravity force and force of friction). To rule out the difficult friction part, and measure the gravity force only, we put the body to rest on a weight scale. This measures gravity force while the body is at test, with zero acceleration. We have a way to measure force without misusing the 2nd law as a definition of force.
When you look into statics, which is a part of mechanics that is often skimmed over too quickly in schools, you will see that force there is a vector, a mathematical concept with magnitude and direction in space, connected with mutual contact of bodies and their deformation. It helps us analyze static equilibrium and safety of rigid constructions: to predict loads on members due to weights or other constant loads, and design constructions so they are stable and safe for prescribed maximum loads. Nothing accelerates and moves in these statics calculations, yet forces are used here with success. So what does "force" mean in this setting?
Force is a vector, it has magnitude and direction in physical space. It characterizes physical interaction (push or pull) of two bodies. It can act at a point (concentrated load), or be distributed on a surface(pressure force), or in a volume(gravity force).
Forces acting at the same point of a body add up as vectors, so we can replace, in calculations, many such forces with one resultant force that is their vector sum.
A body is in static equilibrium if 1) vector sum of all forces acting on it equals zero, and if 2) vector sum of all moments of force(torques) acting on it equals zero.
Forces in statics also obey Newton's 3rd law: when body A acts on body B with force $\mathbf F_{AB}$, then the body B acts on the body A with force $\mathbf F_{BA}$ of equal magnitude, but opposite direction, so we have $\mathbf F_{BA} = - \mathbf F_{AB}$. This law is arguably part of the concept of force in statics. It turns out to not be valid in some situations with motion and magnetic forces, but that is a more advanced topic, not necessary to understand what force is in mechanics.
When you understand this concept of force, and solve a few statics problems, you'll see there is no need to think of acceleration and Newton's 2nd law, or changes of momentum, to understand this basic notion of force. Newton's second law is really meant to be a law about motion of bodies in presence of known forces, not to be a definition of force.
Special relativity and experiments supporting it have shown that 2nd law is only approximate; if the speed of the body is high enough, it does not hold. So it would be incorrect even numerically to use it to define force. E.g. when force is due to electric field $\mathbf F = q\mathbf E$, this is valid irrespective of the speed of the charged particle, but it is equal to $m\mathbf a$ only in the limit of zero speed.

Regarding your last paragraph: isn't it true though that the relativistic generalization of Newton's 2nd law remains completely correct? (four force defined as the proper time rate of change of four momentum).

@Amit Yes, but it shows that 2nd law is really an approximate law, and we can expect the same about the special relativistic version - there may be small deviations in case of strong fields.

TLDR; "Force is just a letter in physicists' equations." ;-)

@user13964273 not just a letter, but a mathematical concept with some rules.

Good answer. Actually it is a very fundamental question. Heinrich Hertz has a whole book dedicated to rewriting mechanics without forces as primary objects.

"Forces are vectors". Not quite, they are line vectors, carrying magnitude and direction along a "line of action" in space. You need some positional information to fully describe a force. There is no such thing as a "pure" force which could be applied arbitrarily anywhere and it wouldn't affect the physics of the problem.

@JAlex yes, forces in physics and already in statics are attached to definite positions in the body and thus any single force acts in definite line in space. I touched on this in my answer.

@Notachance How can one define inertial frames or (classical) mass without the notion of force?

@M.Winter You might like to read his book :) He is not very rigorous about frames, but neither was Newton. To your question: what is a force? Do you have a single definition for it? You will use it here to define inertial frames, and there to define mass and elsewhere for other purposes but it will, I think, always be some ostensive definition. Momentum and position are much more natural as primary objects, aren't they? Grüße aus dem M-Gebäude

@M.Winter, similarly to the answer by J.Murray, he defines first a free system as one which moves on geodesics. So perhaps in that way you can find your inertial system as one for which the momentum is constant. For him all systems are free, or part of a larger system that is free.

I would say Force is an interaction that tends to change the momentum of an object.
"Tends to" because static forces in equilibrium do not actually result in momentum change.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I like to think about Force in 3 steps:

We know by experience the effort to push, pull or lift something heavy. And we can say within a certain range and coarse precision if a force we do is greater than another.

By the elastic property of the materials we can relate our subjective perception with the measured displacements consequence of a force. Force is now what a strain gage or load cell measures.

We note that, under net forces measured as (2), there is a fairly good linear relation between a given mass and its acceleration. Force now can be updated to the second law of Newton, that can be used to calibrate a measuring device. Any small non-linearity is attributed to the stress x strain property of the material.


Combining these 3 points we can make a definition similar to Einstein about time: Force is what load cells measures.

This doesn't make sense at all, like how will you go on defining forces load cells can't measure like strong nuclear force or forces between planets etc.. Also using vague and subjective things like sensory perception into such a fundamental definition doesn't seem appropriate.

It is the same about time. How we could put a clock to follow a muon falling down to the ground close to light speed to measure its proper time? But we use the concept that time is what clocks measure.


But here’s where the problem arises: if we use the concept of "force" to define what an inertial frame is, aren’t we just going in circles?

No, there's nothing circular about this definition. A formalization of Newtonian (point) mechanics might look like this:

Objects generically move under the influence of forces, which are influences which serve to change their state of motion. The laws governing forces make this more precise:
1: When no forces act on an object, it maintains it natural state of motion. There exist reference frames in which this natural state of motion corresponds to a constant velocity; these frames are called inertial.
2: In an inertial frame, the sum of the forces acting on an object is proportional to its acceleration. The constant of proportionality is the object's inertial mass.
3: Whenever two objects exert forces on one another, the forces are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.

You might object to this by saying that nowhere is "force" given a real, fully-rigorous definition, which is true. However, when making formal definitions you will always have terms which aren't defined explicitly. As a point of comparison, you may find amusing that ZF set theory does not actually define what sets are. In a sense, forces are defined implicitly by the laws which govern them.

In point #2, you are implicitly assuming forces are Cartesian vectors. There's a reason introductory physics classes teach about vectors before they start teaching about Newtonian mechanics. Newton "derived" this as a pair of corollaries, but the reasoning was rather circular. Some physics instructors view the vectorial nature of forces as "Newton's fourth law" (or even better, as "Newton's zeroth law").

@DavidHammen I don't think I assume that, if you interpret "sum" as "the resultant force obtained by applying multiple forces simultaneously."

You have to know several histories to know this:
1. Force
Force is word chosen in newtonian mechanics to link with rate of change of momentum, Force until then had no physical proper definition except a language meaning as it is understood today,push or pull.
Newtonian mechanics took the word Force from english and assigned it to rate of change of momentum.
You were saying how could it then be a law but it would merely be a definition, yes it is right that the law is more like definition of force.
Mechanics can be solved without use of force, you are asking about definition of force,which naturally have meaning. And its meaning came after newton only, note that force could have also be defined as twice the rate of change of momentum.
Or even force could have been defined as mass*rate of change of momentum, which is dimensionally different itself, the new force will be higher in value than old force for same physical push. but it is nothing wrong to use 90N(just consider magnitude dont be serious with unit) instead of 30N for a 3kg object, by it we are linking 90 unit force with mass of 3 unit mass by earth, we can get new laws of motion, equations, etc.
If your question is about how you can think of force as, not the definition, you can think of it as how you have been taught to, such words can not be explained with further words,except push,pull, then your question will not belong to physics at all,but about language-physical/mental meaning connection than a word-physics definition.The question is then like "what is a point/line/etc." Euclidean geometries, which are understood that defined as they are language-meaning oriented
2. Inertial frame  - This is truly a nice question:
Inertial frame concept is a drawback of newtonian mechanics view!

"Newton viewed the first law as valid in any reference frame that is in uniform motion (neither rotating nor accelerating) relative to absolute space; as a practical matter, "absolute space" was considered to be the fixed stars"

this definition as you said is going around circles,pointed out by einstein:

Einstein says: "The weakness of the principle of inertia lies in this, that it involves an argument in a circle: a mass moves without acceleration if it is sufficiently far from other bodies; we know that it is sufficiently far from other bodies only by the fact that it moves without acceleration."

and

The existence of absolute space contradicts the internal logic of classical mechanics since, according to the Galilean principle of relativity, none of the inertial frames can be singled out.
Absolute space does not explain inertial forces since they are related to acceleration with respect to any one of the inertial frames.
Absolute space acts on physical objects by inducing their resistance to acceleration but it cannot be acted upon.
— Milutin Blagojević: Gravitation and Gauge Symmetries, p. 5

But then came a more functional definition of inertial frame coined by Ludwig Lange in 1885

"A reference frame in which a mass point thrown from the same point in three different (non co-planar) directions follows rectilinear paths each time it is thrown, is called an inertial frame."

Note that An object is said to be in a rectilinear motion when two objects are moving in a straight line and are parallel to each other.
Explanation, lets say your'e in a frame that is at rest or at uniform motion, i.e. inertial as you know now, then it is defined inertial/proved to be by above definition, if you throw three balls in three mutually perpendicular direction(assuming the balls experience no force after throwing) the frame is inertial if it is not accelerating with respect to all three balls i.e. all four move parallel at same velocity, else non inertial, like if you throw three balls from a accelerating train, the train is defined non inertial as it is accelerating with respect to three balls not all four objects move parallel, rectilinear after throwing, but if it was moving with constant velocity, then a rectilinear path is shown by four objects, none accelerating.

Italic quotes "" are from wikipedia quotations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference
P.S: I am not proving this answer saying it is from wikipedia, but only from statements of definition from history which I took from wikipedia.

A force is a pull or push that affects the motion of an object.

This is a difficult question to answer because in a certain view of things, 'force' itself is fundamental, indeed, the sole fundamental property of reality apart from space itself: in other words, there is nothing more physically fundamental in terms of which 'force' may be defined.  The idea therefore becomes descriptive.  Indeed, in practice, there is no empirical context (nor any experimental context, in the case in which forces are expressly applied) which can be described analytically without either alluding to, inferring or explicitly invoking the idea of 'force'; as the OP suggests in reference to 'inertial frames', the essence of the concept simply cannot be expunged from scenarios of physical mechanics.
So, in exploring the fundamental nature of the very idea of 'force', it is perhaps instructive to consider the original opinion of Faraday in imagining the existence of a singular universal substance of which all reality is composed -- which in the ideation of his day required one to envisage no ultimate qualitative distinction between 'aether' and 'matter' -- that such a substance or universal fabric is or would be effectively indistinguishable from the correspondingly unitary fundamental force holding it together.  While, as I recall, that view does not explicitly state its reasoning, it seems clear that such a practical constraint arises because the sole means of apprehending the nature of such a substance (for those such as we who are also comprised entirely of it) is through a mechanism of resonance between components of that force -- let us call it a 'cohesive force' -- comprising one's being and those components extrinsic to us in the exterior world.
Moreover, the very effect that a universal substance would be perceptible in such a way is inevitably due not merely to the disparity between these contexts, but to the further effect that such a substance must exist in a condition of perpetual inertia: in the following treatment of such a conception, not only does the state of alignment between components of the fundamental cohesive force tend to be maintained universally -- which is only to say that the condition of relative equilibrium between opposing components tends to be sustained --, but must from a philosophical standpoint tend inexorably towards increase.
To understand what is meant here by 'alignment' of such components, and its equivalence to a condition of 'cohesive resonance' between them, consider that in order to conceive the appropriate geometrical model of such a unitary universal substance based on the self-evident presumption that a unitary and exclusive fundamental 'cohesive force' inheres within it, it is first necessary to imply what amounts to a correspondingly unitary universal 'field' in which all points are in some degree of interaction with all others mediated solely by such a force.  (Indeed, Faraday's conception of 'fields' is presumably that these represent the organisation of components of such a force and their integration in more-or-less recognisable ways in various contexts within the universal entity.).
As is evident, force imagined in such a fundamental way may be said to act only against itself, in an infinite array of disparate components distributed universally to the end of an ideal condition of ultimate equilibrium or cohesive symmetry; and it is this fundamental tendency which is equivalent to that of both an alignment between components of cohesive force, and in the case of opposing components, their state of relative equilibrium or 'cohesive equilibration: the two ideas are equivalent to that of 'resonance' between such components.  It should be emphasised however that no true symmetry exists within this reality, only the inexorable proclivity towards such an idealised state.
Regarding any two loci in such a 'field' -- broadly a tensor/vector field --, it is self-evidently true that, since a condition of perfect equilibrium or symmetry between any such points implies immediate universal cessation, the cohesive interaction between them must be disparate: viz, a resultant in cohesive force or fundamental polarity must arise between them.  At the same time, since it is the primary postulate of such a conception that all such interaction is the manifestation of a singular universal impetus towards such a state of cohesive equilibrium or symmetry, then the dynamic interaction between such disparate components of cohesive force may be modeled within a conceptual framework representing this ultimately idealised state of cohesive symmetry or equilibrium.
In order to represent this idealised state, one may immediately propose a cubic lattice-type model in which each cubic vertex in two interlocking reciprocal aspects represents such a locus of cohesive force; and in that conceptual context, the geometry of such a structure in which fundamental polarities or resultants in cohesive force are implied by the disparities between the 3 cubic dimensions (the pole, edge and face diagonal) -- thus 3 basic fundamental vectors of cohesive force arising at a common frequency -- permits the inference of a basic wave interference effect between these resultants (or fundamental vectors of cohesive polarity) whose dynamics of progression and recurrence with respect to the idealised lattice structure of 'cohesive symmetry' constitutes the basis on which a 'unitary universal cohesive field' may be modeled within which such a unitary oscillatory wave principle is inherent.
'Force' then in such a conception is truly fundamental; not only should the 4 'fundamental forces' of physics be understood as aspects of such a unitary universal force construed in varying contexts, but all other physical properties and quantities, energy and momentum in particular, are measures of the inter-relation between and integration of components of such a fundamental 'cohesive force'.  Even 'charge' is postulated in this model as a radial component in the expanding plane of intersection between two opposing components of cohesive force operating in the cubic polar axis of the lattice model suggested.
That is, imagining such an interaction in mutual cohesion between disparate components as two intersecting spheres centred at points on an axis, a plane of distribution of that resultant force arising between them will expand from its point of origin orthogonal to that axis: a plane of 'cohesive tension' (curving towards the stronger locus of force); and it is in such planes that 'charge' is defined in this model.  Moreover, it is this essential orthogonal relation between the cohesive force along a cubic axis and the plane of its distribution which is at the basis of orthogonality between electric and magnetic aspects of EM fields in the orthodox analysis, indeed, of all orthogonality between quantities and functions in the SM including complex functions.
For those curious about the potential value of such a conception and its model of a 'unitary universal (cohesive) force field', certain basic physical quantities and measures may be readily inferred from it, in particular, the neutron-proton and muon-electron mass ratios; a value for the range of visible light frequencies of dominant solar EMR when a specific temporal periodicity is imputed to the unitary universal oscillatory wave (interference) dynamic; the geometric basis for the 'fine structure constant', and the physical basis for Planck's constant.  One may of course refuse to concede the premise itself of an effectively inviolate unitary universal entity, and of the concept of a correspondingly unitary 'universal substance or fabric', moreover to repudiate the logical corollaries of a unitary cohesive force, and the singular impetus towards an idealised state of symmetry between its components following from those premises -- in which case one will be left with the parlous state of orthodox physics and cosmology as it is, an engineering masterpiece to be sure, but quite incapable introspectively of addressing even the most fundamental of questions such as that posed here.

As @jalex commented, force is the rate of change of momentum.
Edit:
The question was substantially edited since my answer. This is my answer to the new second part:
An inertial reference frame is defined by a constant total momentum.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
